# Trouble running Cardboard Treasure Hunt sample

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm running the latest Android Studio v0.8 and I am trying to get the Treasure Hunt Android app sample to work on my Note II, after a few changes, I still cannot get the app to work and also I have already imported the cardboard.jar library. The demo app would start on my phone then crash the error shown on LogCat is this:

```
07-31 15:28:50.803  19490-19503/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt E/checkGlError﹕ onReadyToDraw: glError INVALID_ENUM
07-31 15:28:50.873  19490-19503/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 713
Process: com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt, PID: 19490
java.lang.RuntimeException: onReadyToDraw: glError INVALID_ENUM
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.checkGLError(MainActivity.java:143)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.onNewFrame(MainActivity.java:311)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView$StereoRendererHelper.onDrawFrame(CardboardView.java:1129)
        at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView$RendererHelper.onDrawFrame(CardboardView.java:968)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java)
```

at MainActivity.java:143

```
    static final void checkGLError(String operationDescription){

    //if(Main.DEBUGGING){//only do the program-crashing thing in debug mode. In release mode, try to ride through errors. Replace my boolean with yours.
        int errorCode;
        while ((errorCode = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            String error;
            switch(errorCode) {
                case GLES20.GL_INVALID_OPERATION:      error="INVALID_OPERATION";      break;
                case GLES20.GL_INVALID_ENUM:           error="INVALID_ENUM";           break;
                case GLES20.GL_INVALID_VALUE:          error="INVALID_VALUE";          break;
                case GLES20.GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:          error="OUT_OF_MEMORY";          break;
                case GLES20.GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:  error="INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION";  break;
                default: error="Unknown error code";
            }
            Log.e("checkGlError", operationDescription + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(operationDescription + ": glError " + error);
        }
```

at MainActivity.java:311

```
 @Override
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mGlProgram);

    mModelViewProjectionParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mGlProgram, "u_MVP");
    mLightPosParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mGlProgram, "u_LightPos");
    mModelViewParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mGlProgram, "u_MVMatrix");
    mModelParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mGlProgram, "u_Model");
    mIsFloorParam = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mGlProgram, "u_IsFloor");

    // Build the Model part of the ModelView matrix.
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelCube, 0, TIME_DELTA, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    // Build the camera matrix and apply it to the ModelView.
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mCamera, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, CAMERA_Z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    headTransform.getHeadView(mHeadView, 0);

    checkGLError("onReadyToDraw");
}
```

The changes I made is at the build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0' -----> previously '19.0.3'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0' -----> previously compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

The error seems to come from:

case GLES20.GL_INVALID_ENUM:           error="INVALID_ENUM";

Did I miss something? And what does that error mean?

Answer (score 1):

GL_INVALID_ENUM means that an enum value passed into one of the methods was invalid.

Take for instance the [glDrawElements](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) method.

The first parameter of that method is supposed to be an enum. If you pass in any Symbolic constant other than the ones listed then you would get this error.

Some constants are only available in specific versions.

In my past an error like this was caused from specifying the build to always use the 'latest' version of any dependencies, and the solution was to figure out the last working version and lock that down in the build file. Upgrading is then a deliberate effort, and helps to keep you safe from unknown errors of bleeding edge libraries.